# How to get Secondary memory(Hard drive) total memory size and available memory size in batch script or vbscript?

Tags: batch-file, vbscript

I need to get total secondary storage size and available memory size using **batch** or **vbscript**.

Comment: What have you already tried?  SO isn't a code writing service, it's a support site where people try to help you resolve the problems you are having with your code....

Comment: [What have you tried so far?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)
Please [edit] your question to show a [mcve] of the code
that you are having problems with, then we can try to help
with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Comment: @Dave,  I tried with the "fsutil volume diskfree C:" command, but I could able to get usage of only "C:\" drive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
wmic logicaldisk get caption,freespace,size
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using freedisk.exe from Windows Resource Kit